# Apache tomhawk <t:inputFileUpload> tag not working

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jsf-2, jsf-1.2

I am trying to upload a file using Apache tomhawk with JSF 2.0, but when I try to navigate to the corresponding view I am getting the following error:

```
javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException: /jsf/importReport.xhtml @30,51 value="#{import.uploadedFile}" Failed to parse the expression [#{import.uploadedFile}]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getValueExpression(TagAttributeImpl.java:401)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getValueExpression(TagAttributeImpl.java:351)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ValueHolderRule$DynamicValueExpressionMetadata.applyMetadata(ValueHolderRule.java:129)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.MetadataImpl.applyMetadata(MetadataImpl.java:81)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.MetaTagHandler.setAttributes(MetaTagHandler.java:129)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.setAttributes(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:102)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.doNewComponentActions(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:402)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:159)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:184)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:103)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:178)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:395)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:366)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:108)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:184)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:186)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:82)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:308)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:367)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:346)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:155)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:82)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:152)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:744)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:509)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [#{import.uploadedFile}]
at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createNodeInternal(ExpressionBuilder.java:146)
at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.build(ExpressionBuilder.java:172)
at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createValueExpression(ExpressionBuilder.java:217)
at org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.createValueExpression(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:67)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getValueExpression(TagAttributeImpl.java:385)
... 87 more
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: The identifier [import] is not a valid Java identifier as required by section 1.19 of the EL specification (Identifier ::= Java language identifier). This check can be disabled by setting the system property org.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK to true.
at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.setImage(AstIdentifier.java:133)
at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.Identifier(ELParser.java:1217)
at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.NonLiteral(ELParser.java:1193)
at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.ValuePrefix(ELParser.java:1019)
at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.Value(ELParser.java:968)
at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.Unary(ELParser.java:950)
at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.Multiplication(ELParser.java:714)
at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.Math(ELParser.java:634)
at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.Compare(ELParser.java:446)
at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.Equality(ELParser.java:340)
at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.And(ELParser.java:284)
at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.Or(ELParser.java:228)
at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.Choice(ELParser.java:185)
at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.Expression(ELParser.java:177)
at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.DeferredExpression(ELParser.java:115)
at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.CompositeExpression(ELParser.java:43)
at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createNodeInternal(ExpressionBuilder.java:115)
... 91 more*
```

I am using the following web.xml:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
<filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>uploadMaxFileSize</param-name>
        <param-value>20m</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>


<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>

    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>


<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/myFacesExtensionResource/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/config/faces-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>

<param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
<param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
<param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
<listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I am using the following JSF code for the view:

```
<ui:define name="content">
<div id="midbody" class="span-24">
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
<t:inputFileUpload value="#{import.uploadedFile}"></t:inputFileUpload>
<h:commandButton action="#{import.getFile}"></h:commandButton>
</h:form>
</div>

</ui:define>
```

My managed bean is as follows:

```
public class ImportMB {
    private UploadedFile uploadedFile;

    public String getFile(){
       String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(uploadedFile.getName());
       try {
InputStream myInput = uploadedFile.getInputStream();
System.out.println(fileName);
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
return "importReport";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look your stacktrace, it says:

javax.el.ELException: The identifier [import] is not a valid Java identifier as required by section 1.19 of the EL specification (Identifier ::= Java language identifier). This check can be disabled by setting the system property org.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK to true.

Change the bean name will work.